# Pass method as array with key as a result of method in other class

Tags: php, class

I have two snippet codes like this:

```
class User()
{
    var $permission = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $Permission_Class = new Permission();
        // What to do here with $this->permission 
        // to linked with $Permission_Class->check_permission() 
        // for getting user's permission?
    }
}

class Permission()
{
    var $permission_list = array(
        'can_read'    => 'yes',
        'can_write'   => 'no'
    );

    public function check_permission($permission_name)
    {
        return $this->permission_list[$permission_name];         
    }
}
```

I want to get the user's permission by simply entering the permission name as an array, especially by this:

```
$User1 = new User();
$read_permission = $User1->permission['can_read']; // not working currently
```

Or even more better like this:

```
$permission = $User1->permission();
var_dump($permission['can_read']); // expected 'yes'
```

So expected results is 'can_read' in class Permission has 'yes' value.
What can I do to get this happen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just wrap it up!

```
class User()
{
    private $permission = array();

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->permission = new Permission();
    }

    public function permission($key)
    {
         return $this->permission->check_permission($key);
    }
}

$user->permission('can_read');
```

Be sure to check if `$key` is an existing key. E.G:

```
/**
 * $default  would contain the value you want your 
 *           requested permission to have if it does not exist
 */
public function check_permission($permission_name, $default = NULL)
{
    return isset($this->permission_list[$permission_name])
        ? $this->permission_list[$permission_name]
        : $default;         
}

// We want can write to be `FALSE` unless otherwise specified
$user->permission('can_write', FALSE);
```

**Update after comment**

Event though I advice against using a global permissions array (e.g. what if you'd want to know whether another user has the can_write permission) you could rewrite some of it easily:

```
/** class User **/
public function permission($key = NULL)
{
     // If no key specified, return entire array
     if($key === NULL)
     {
        return $this->permission->permission_list;
     }

     return $this->permission->check_permission($key); 
}
```

Then somewhere in your application

```
global $permissions;
$permissions = $user->permission();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer :) However, are there any way for me to access the permission as a global array, not by passing method? Eg. I want to use $permission['can_read'] and it will directly output 'yes'. So what to do with variable $permission for getting this?

Comment: If you are insisting on using global variables (which is not recommended) you could make `$user` global.

Comment: Can you point me out in this? Sorry I was a little confused. What I want exactly is, I want $permission to be an global permission array, that has the index as the argument in the check_permission() method. Example, $permission['can_read'] will equal 'yes', and $permission['can_write'] will give us 'no'. Means $permission = some kind of implementation => $permission['can_read'] => the class Permission will run check_permission('can_read') and return the value, give it back to $permission['can_read']. Because I don't want to use any kind of class at the end, just plain variable.

Comment: You could take a look at the [`ArrayAccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface or one of its relatives. I cannot help you with those as I have never used it. Just use an array, seriously, don't go mix around OOP and procedural code and waste my/our time.